# BigQuery preview: Unknown error response from the server

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting an "Unknown error response from the server" error on a lot of my datasets, when trying to do a preview. I have this already since a couple of days with no workaround to fix it. Do you have any idea, what's happening or how to solve this? Is there a bug tracker for BigQuery or some other way to reach out to the Google Platform staff?

[image: Unknown error response from the server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens due to the request (created during "preview" command) being too large for some tables with a lot of fields. We are implementing a partial solution where we reduce the size of the request. The changes are currently being pushed in all regions ([issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158236532)).